# Assigning class based on scroll causing conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to add/remove css classes when user scroll the page according to the visible div.

I have two blocks (white and black).
Now I'm doing this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {

   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

   if(scroll >= $('div.white').offset().top){
       //do things
   }

   if(scroll >= $('div.black').offset().top){
       //do things
   }
}
```

The problem occurs when there is an alternance between the two classes, when a `.white` div follows a `.black` one. How can I better write this?

Thank you.

Comment: FInd the outerHeight of the div.white and add.

Comment: thanks @sridharreddy could you please give me an example?

Comment: When white div follows black div wait untill you scroll the whitediv height and add/removeclass.
scroll > $('div.white').offset().top + $('div.white').outerHeight()

Answer (score 0):

Solved editing the calculation considering both the top offset and the element height.

```
if(scroll >= $('.bianco').offset().top && scroll <= ($('.bianco').offset().top + $('.bianco').height()) ){
    //code to be executed
}
```

Thank you